# C++ fire an event once

Tags: c++, c++03

*I am stuck at C++ 98*

I have written a basic event system in C++, similar to how things are done in scripting languages.

Events/callbacks are stored in a map

`std::hash_map<uint32_t, std::vector<EVENTHANDLER> >`

API example

```
ES es;
es.On("MyEvent", MyCallback);

Event event(1,2,3);
es.Emit("MyEvent", event);

es.Off("MyEvent", MyCallback);
```

I want to implement the typical `One` method, where after the callback is executed, it is then removed so that it only ever fires once. In JS this is easy, you can wrap the callback in an anonymous function

```
one(event, cb){
    this.on(event, (e) => {
        cb(e);
        this.off(event, cb);
     });
}
```

But I cannot use lambda in C++ 98. Is there any other trivial way to do this? I thought maybe if a callback registers with "one" it can be put into a vector of "one" callbacks that must be iterated each time an event is emitted, but that is a backup solution.

Comment: "I am stuck at C++ 98" - Your main priority should be to fix that (IMHO).

Comment: I'm on vxworks and have no control over this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with lambdas - lambda is just like a regular function. Nothing special. I think you are confusing Javascript with C++. C++ is not not asynchronous. And before you start to reinvent a square wheel, look at solutions that already exist, like Boost.Signals2 or even Boost.Signals if you are stuck in the past.

Comment: I think the only reasonable way would be to write your own polymorphic `Callback` class, which could include a `Callback` derived class which augmented a supplied callback with the unregistering operation.

Comment: BTW, you can just declare `es` as `ES es;`. `new` would actually be incorrect here, since `es` is just an instance of the `ES` class, not a pointer to such an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any reason your `ES` can't do this.

- Add the capability to call `es.Once("MyEvent", MyCallback);`
- Have this and `es.On` set a boolean flag inside wherever you're storing these things, `bool once`
- After running a task, if `task.once`, just do `Off(TheEventImRunning, TheCallbackItUses)`.

So it's the logic you proposed, but without using a lambda. Just write it normally in your functions, with a boolean stored somewhere to decide whether or not the extra logic needs to be run.

Alternatively, you could consider *binding* `MyCallback` to some wrapper that additionally does the `Off()` call. If `MyCallback` is just a function pointer or a `std::function` then this is probably quite easy. But we cannot give concrete examples without knowing more about your code.

Comment: I added how events/callbacks are stored in my question. I guess I would have to change my vector of callbacks to be a a vector of simple objects as you described, with a flag and with the actual callback.